# The type or namespace 'GenericPrincipal' could not be found ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to follow  [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Role-based-security-Page-access-and-ShowHide-Menu-items-based-on-Role-in-ASPNet.aspx) Role-based security tutorial.

In Global.asax, I am getting the following error:

[image: snip1]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `using System.Security.Principal` to the top.

In *Visual Studio 2015* (maybe other versions too), if you see a squiggly line, you can put the cursor over the squiggly line, and then press:

```
CTRL + .
```

and Visual Studio will show you a bunch of options to fix the issue. One option shown for the above case would be to add `using System.Security.Principal` and you simply select the option. And that will fix it. This is a very useful tool and every developer should be aware of it. Of course, you can add the `using System.Security.Principal` manually too; just by typing it.